# Bulk Insert not working with Android 4.4 or any version < 5

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I had created two functions for insert in sqlite,

In Android 5 or greater both working fine.

And in Android 4 or down, Single Insert works fine,

But, on **Bulk Insert** it through an error

***`could not prepare statement (1 near ",": syntax error)`***

**Single Insert**

```
            function insert(TABLENAME, COLNAME, VALNAME, callBack) {

                var query = "INSERT INTO " + TABLENAME + "(" + COLNAME + ") VALUES (" + VALNAME + ") ";
                $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
                    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function (res) {
                        console.log("INSERT " + TABLENAME + " -> " + res);
                        if (callBack)
                            callBack();
                    }, function (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    });
                });
            }
```

**Bulk Insert**

```
            function bulkInsert(TABLENAME, COLNAME, VALNAMES, DATA, callBack) {

                var query = "INSERT INTO " + TABLENAME + "(" + COLNAME + ") VALUES ";
                var data = DATA;
                var rowArgs = [];
                query += VALNAMES.join(", ");
                $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, data).then(function (res) {
                    console.log("inserted");
                    if (callBack)
                        callBack();
                }, function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });

            }
```

Can anyone help me out, how do i fix this issue??

PS: Bulk insert parameter will be like this,

***`bulkInsert('users', 'id,name', ['(?,?)','(?,?)'], [[1,'abc'],[2,'xyz']], function(){});`***

**I am asking about Cordova-SQLite not Android SQLite**